# How to improve performance of this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

(I work on php and MySQL)

Here's the situation : through an ajax request, I check each 10sec if there's something new for the user in the *calendars* he's part of.

There are a few things to check, for each *calendars* (w/e it's a calendar or an other element, but in this case, it's a calendar), so I did a "big" query to return all datas for each *calendars*, and I treat it with php, and then with js (to pop notifications or w/e).

Three things to check :

- is there a "dates" modification since he last visited the calendar ?
- is there a new talk in the chat's calendar since he last saw it ?
- is there a request to join the calendar which has no answer ?

I did it this way :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ci.ci_cid as c_id,
  MAX(cc.cc_timestamp) as chat_lastmsg, umchat.um_value as chat_lastview,
  MAX(cr.cr_id) as request_id,
  cmodif.cm_value as modification_timestamp,
  umodif.um_value as modification_view
FROM c_individuals as ci
  LEFT JOIN c_chats as cc ON cc.cc_cid = ci.ci_cid
   LEFT JOIN u_metas as umchat ON (umchat.um_uid = ci.ci_ciuid AND umchat.um_cid = ci.ci_cid AND umchat.um_name = "chat_last_view")
  LEFT JOIN c_requests as cr ON (cr.cr_cid = ci.ci_cid AND cr.cr_answer = "0")
  LEFT JOIN c_metas as cmodif ON (cmodif.cm_cid = ci.ci_cid AND cmodif.cm_name = "last_modifications")
   LEFT JOIN u_metas as umodif ON (umodif.um_uid = ci.ci_uid AND umodif.um_cid = ci.ci_cid AND umodif.um_name = "last_view")
WHERE ci.ci_uid = :u_id
GROUP BY ci.ci_cid
```

- The `c_individuals` table has the users who are in a calendar.
- The `u_metas` table has users'metas with `um_uid`(user id), `um_cid` (calendar id related to the meta), `um_name` (name of the meta), `um_value` (value of the meta)
- The `c_requests` table has requests'informations (u_id, c_id, answer and stuff)

My query gives me what I want, meaning something like :

```
0 => 
array (size=6)
  'c_id' => string '50' (length=2)
  'chat_lastmsg' => null
  'chat_lastview' => null
  'request_id' => null
  'modification_timestamp' => string '1488878397.703508' (length=17)
  'modification_view' => string '1488877914.048585' (length=17)
1 => 
array (size=6)
  'c_id' => string '51' (length=2)
  'chat_lastmsg' => string '1485326492' (length=10)
  'chat_lastview' => string '1488470529' (length=10)
  'request_id' => null
  'modification_timestamp' => string '1488878397.703508' (length=17)
  'modification_vue' => string '1488878065.811320' (length=17)
```

But to be honest, I think it's kinda slow. Without treatment, so just to get the results of the query, it takes like 3.5sec to repeat it 1000 times.

It's not a big deal, but this query is repeated a lot, for a potential big number of users.

**So my question is : is there any way to improve it, or am I good with this ?**

Thank you for your time, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will raise an error on newer MySQL version (unless in compatibility mode), or return an unpredictable result on older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Ok @jarlh, I can hear that but how should I write it then ? If I don't put the GROUP BY thing, the query returns only one iteration of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record,

I finally found something much faster (on my "benchmark test", it's five to seven times faster).

The fact is I don't need to get the informations (dates etc), I just want to know if there is something new since the user saw it for the last time, whenever it was, whenever the new thing was posted.

So I made this (it's in french, plz don't bother) :

```
SELECT
  ci.ci_cid as c_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(cc_id)
    FROM c_chats 
    LEFT JOIN u_metas ON um_nom = "chat_derniere_vue" 
   WHERE cc_cid = ci.ci_cid AND um_uid = ci.ci_uid AND um_cid = ci.ci_cid AND CAST(cc_timestamp as decimal) > CAST(um_valeur as decimal)
  ) as chat,
  (SELECT COUNT(cr_id)
    FROM c_requetes
   WHERE cr_cid = ci.ci_cid AND ci.ci_ustatut = "titulaire" AND cr_reponse = "0"
  ) as notifications,
  (SELECT COUNT(cm_cid)
    FROM c_metas 
    LEFT JOIN u_metas ON um_nom = "derniere_vue"
   WHERE um_uid = ci.ci_uid AND um_cid = ci.ci_cid AND cm_cid = ci.ci_cid AND cm_nom = "derniere_modification_periodes" AND CAST(cm_valeur as decimal) > CAST(um_valeur as decimal)
  ) as modifications
FROM c_individus as ci
WHERE ci.ci_uid = :u_id 
GROUP BY ci.ci_cid
```

In this way, `chat` gives the number of chats with a new message, `notifications` gives the number of unanswer requests, `modifications` gives the number of calendars with new dates.

And "tada" !

Answer (score 0):

Don't see anything wrong with your posted query except that you don't need `DISTINCT` since you are doing a `GROUP BY`. Also, make sure you have proper index on the columns which are used in `JOIN ON` condition and `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I have this reflex to put DISTINCT on too many queries.... Thx for the answer. And indexes are goodly set (I hope) ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a system/database design question rather than a query design.

The query looks adequate enough, and gives the results that you expect, so it's fine (although unsure why you need LEFT joins - but that's down to your data.)

Things to consider in the system design space:

- Denormalising the database structure - whenever you enter a c_chat or
  c_request, etc. you could look to store the latest timestamp against
  the user, so you aren't doing joins - which are very slow.
- Could you benefit from a cache closer to the server (e.g. Memcache)?
  if you have lots of requests you may want to look into it if the
  database is slow. You    probably don't need a cache if you're
  denormalising the database.
- Indexing on anything you use as a filter in the WHERE if you use more than just the Id

Comment: Thx for your answer.
I don't understand the first point (about sotring the latest timestamp) ? Sorry, english is not my first language (as you can see haha). I'll check again if a "cache" is in place, but I'm pretty sure I did it on my live server (those results are in local). For the indexing thing, it's already done ! Thx again.

Comment: @Vae the first point requires a little more management on inserts; when you save a chat message, you also store the time of the message, etc. in the user table. Chats will likely have a big table: expensive to join and aggregate on (max/min). Storing a snapshot of time will speed the read query. You may want it per conversation, where a conversation table acts as a summary of all chats, incl. timestamps and count, etc.. Basically: do some duplicating of data on save to avoid the slow reads. Does that clarify it at all?

Comment: Yes, it does actually. Thanks.
But as you say, a user can have differents chats (cause chats are linked to calendars). I thought about storing last_msg_timestamp or else in an other table (created for it, or in the calendars' one), but I was wondering if it wouldn't be slower to edit this data a lot (a few users can talk in a chat at the same time) than just refering to the MAX(msg)... What do you think ?

Comment: It is entirely up to where you want the performance to be. It would be a smaller table where you're storing the last_msg_timestamp field, so inserts will likely be minimally impacted, but calling MAX() on a chat table is almost guaranteed to become slow as the table grows. Having said that, indexing on the time stamps could make it faster - I am not 100% sure of the impact of indexes on MAX. If you'd asked me a few years back, I would have said just use MAX, but these days I would tend to pre-aggregate the data for querying (in SQL Server, with another table)

Comment: Thx for this conversation. I'll think about this. In the other hand, I changed the function a lot (see my answer below) so I don't need MAX() anymore, but I'll keep that in mind for the future !